# Why isn't the page cal back needed in Ajax jQuery?

Tags: 6, routes

In the following code, I didn't set any page arguments, but I can still tse the parameter in `example_result()`. Why it works?

```php
function example_menu() {
  $items['example-menu'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'example_result',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,  
  );
  
  return $items;
}

function example_result($para) {
  $items = array('a', 'b', 'c');
  return drupal_json(array('values' => $items));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: And why do you care? You know, we can't write documentation on inner workings here, it would be probably too broad task. Without knowing why you need that information, what's your goal, it might not be feasible to write reasonably short, yet useful answer. [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says: *"You should only ask (...) questions based on actual problems that you face." and there is a reason for it. Last but not least, we use CMS to avoid re-inventing what's already implemented and caring about "how" as long as possible, don't we all? :)

Answer (score 0):

That is explained in the examples shown for [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

```
 function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
    // ...
  }
```

Using the code above, and accessing the page as `http://example.com/abc/def`, the page callback would get `0` and `''` as arguments; accessing the page as `http://example.com/abc/def/123/foo`, `$ghi` will be equal to `123`, while `$jkl` will be equal to `'foo'`.

That is the default behavior of Drupal.

You could also use wildcards arguments, but in that case those arguments should be passed in the URL.